# RAILS 6 - using jquery-ui - autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I want to use the autocomplete function in jquery-ui in a RAILS 6 application.

So I followed this guide : [gist.github.com/.../#jquery-jquery-ui](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/2612fa987b9f9ed7cb53a88fcba247b3#jquery-jquery-ui)

I was able to run rails assets:precompile.

When I start the RAILS server in production mode and check the browser console, I see this error:
**jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).autocomplete is not a function**

So this javascript pack is no correct bundled by webpacker.

Any idea ?